# How to convert month to week to this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
;With CTE_Mem as (
Select m.PeopleID , m.Operator, m.LocationName,     
  sum(case when M.ActiveStart < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND M.ActiveEnd 
 > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as No_of_Live_Member , 
 sum(case when M.ActiveEnd BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) and 
 DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,Getdate())  , -1)  then 1 else 0 end) as No_of_Member_Cancelled
From dbo.Memberships m
Group by m.PeopleID , m.Operator, m.LocationName
 ) 
Select * from CTE_Mem
```

I want to calculate the last month Aug 1st to Aug 31 weeks and convert the above query month to week and shows also which week is?

Please check this for tabular format results:

Format results
[image]

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps `datepart(iso_week, thedate)` might work

Comment: On what day does your "week 1" begin? August 1, 2020 was a Saturday. So, would August 3 (a Monday) be part of week 1 or week 2? Would Monday, August 31 be considered part of the last week of August, or the first week of September?

Comment: Week Start begin Aug 3 (a Monday) but we can take week 1 start from Aug 1, 2020 .

Comment: please update your question with your definition of week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I know what you are attempting to do, however, you lack details in your schema and there are gaps on how you want to obtain the final results. Here is a basic date math query that partitions date by an id ranked within each month/year combination found in the data. This *might* help you get from A->B.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, ActiveStart DATETIME)

INSERT @T VALUES 
    (1,'08/05/2020'),
    (1,'08/10/2020'),
    (1,'08/20/2020'),
    (2,'08/20/2020'),
    (2,'08/20/2021')
;
WITH WeekValuesWithID AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        YearNumber = DATEPART(YEAR,ActiveStart),
        MonthNumber = DATEPART(MONTH,ActiveStart),
        WeekNumberInMonth = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR,ActiveStart), DATEPART(MONTH,ActiveStart) ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK,ActiveStart))
    FROM
        @T
)

SELECT
    IDCount = COUNT(ID),
    WeekNumberInMonth,
    MonthNumber,
    YearNumber
FROM
    WeekValuesWithID
GROUP BY
    WeekNumberInMonth,
    MonthNumber,
    YearNumber
```